# Is there a way to retrieve all map features available in overpass QL?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

In Overpass QL you can filter nodes for specific map features.
Like `"tourism"="museum"` or `"aerialway"="mixed_lift"`.

They can be used to filter for things like so: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1md1

Here you can see all the map features available in overpass QL:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features

My question is:
Is there an API call i can make against https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter in order to retreive all map features that exist?

Is there some other API of OSM that can do that?

I am working on a project where i need to show them all in a list and would love to not manually copy them from the wiki into a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a query is even contained in the examples at https://overpass-turbo.eu/. Select Load -> Examples -> Map Call. This returns the following query:

```
/*
This is a simple map call.
It returns all data in the bounding box.
*/
[out:xml];
(
  node({{bbox}});
  <;
);
out meta;
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. I might have not stated it clearly enough.
I don't want to find all nodes inside a bbox.

I am trying to get all the map features one can search for in OSM.
With map features i mean things like "tourism"="museum" or "aerialway"="mixed_lift".

Comment: There is no exhaustive list for this. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases/EN have long lists about the most common tags.

Comment: Awesome!!
I did not find https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases/EN when i was searching around.

Thank you!!